# How can I improve airflow from this cabinet-enclosed PTAC/HVAC unit?

Tags: hvac, carpentry

I have a through-wall PTAC unit in an apartment building. It's enclosed in some cabinetry with a stone top. The stone top has a grille in it that is supposed to allow air to flow out of the PTAC into the room.

However, presumably because of the angle of the vent on the PTAC, the air gets trapped inside the cabinet and the room is not effectively heated/cooled.

Any ideas for how I could redirect the air straight upwards?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I've ever seen one of those enclosed like that.  Is it getting enough inflow?  If the intake air is restricted, you'll lose output as well as possibly causing the coils to ice up.

As for directing the outflow, you could try making a "boot" out of sheet metal to direct air up and out of the grate.  Even thick paperboard or cardboard taped in the corners would probably work.  You just want to create as smooth as possible of a surface to keep the flow as unrestricted as possible.